# Hijacking expressjs view engine outside http res context

Tags: email, templates, node.js

I am building a small app primarily with socket io, however with a few things from expressjs.

One function of the socket io piece is to send an email when a certain event occurs. I've got this working fine with node_mailer.

The problem I'm running into is that I want to use the express view engine to render the emails from template files. The render method seems to be explicitly attached to the res object prototype.

What I've done feels pretty dirty:

```
// setup express server
var render;
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    if (typeof render == 'undefined') render = res.render;
    res.end('Welcome to app');
});

// socket io code
socket.on('event', function (data) {
    var email_content;
    render('template', {}, function (err, result) { email_content = result; });
});
```

Is there a better way to gain access to expressjs's components outside the context of an http request, or even a better way to approach this problem? I tried rigging up a call to the exported express.view.compile function but that both didn't work and seemed like a high hoo

Comment: which template engine are you using? Jade?

Comment: JinJS, I get the impression that express is somewhat agnostic as to what template engine it uses. It requires that template engines export a certain set of interface implementations in order to be express compatible.

Comment: express is built on connect which is designed to be as agnostic as possible and express mostly adds some sensible defaults.  a `var render = require('JinJS').render` or the like would be best imo.

Comment: var render = require('JinJS').render where did you get this from?

Comment: var render = require('JinJS').render this obviously does not work.. "or the like" is basically exactly what im asking about in this question - after scanning through the code and trying several methods of accessing expresses view engine components I was not able to get to a point of being able to render a template to a string. I ended up moving the request to http (using ajax instead of triggering on the email on a socket action, but thinking about having emails being queued and sent in bulks - how would one accomplish this using these tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is where  the information you seek comes from:

https://github.com/Ravelsoft/node-jinjs/wiki

With templates as modules
To have node load your templates as if they were modules, you first have to register your module extension :

```
require("jinjs").registerExtension(".tpl");
```

If you want your file to be transformed prior to being submitted to jinjs, you can pass a callback ;

```
var pwilang = require("pwilang");
require("jinjs").registerExtension(".pwx", function (txt) { 
    return pwilang.parse(txt); 
});
```

You can now write this to user Jin:

```
var my_template = require("./mytemplate");
var context = { foo: "foo", bar: "bar" };
var result = my_template.render(context);
```

Because you are sticking Jin into express (as opposed to making express work with Jin) this is your best option. The res variable is only available in the route callback.

Answer (score 1):

On express 3.x there is the alias `app.render`

```
// socket io code
socket.on('event', function (data) {
  var email_content;
  app.render('template', {}, function (err, result) { email_content = result; });
});
```